# Doctrine - Is it possible to associate a column result with an other column result instead of her column name

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

Sorry for this unclear question.
I don't know how to explain what I want in words without sample code so for the first time I couldn't find a solution on the web and I'm here.

I am working on a Symfony 3.4 project with Doctrine.
I do the following query with the Doctrine querybuilder :

```
$this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p.email', 'pa.value','a.key')
    ->from('myEntity', 'p')
    ->join('myOtherEntity', 'pa', Join::WITH, 'pa.myEntity = p.id', )
    ->join('anOtherOneEntity', 'a', Join::WITH, 'a.id = pa.anOtherOneEntity')
```

It give me the following result :

```
Array
(
    [email] => test@test.com
    [value] => 758433
    [key] => postalcode
)
Array
(
    [email] => test@test.com
    [value] => John
    [key] => firstname
)
Array
(
    [email] => test@test.com
    [value] => Doe
    [key] => lastname
)
```

I would like to `->groupBy('email')` and get this result:

```
Array
(
    [email] => test@test.com
    [postalcode] => 758433
    [firstname] => John
    [lastname] => Doe
)
```

I have tried to update `myEntity` to get the association value with:

```
private $myAttribute

public function getMyAttribute()
```

And my query

```
$this->em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('p.email', 'p.myAttribute')
     ->from('myEntity', 'p')
```

but i got the following error:

```
Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\myEntity has no field or association named myAttrib
  ute
```

I think the solution is to change my first query but i need some help.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple enough in PHP just build the desired array from the result.

```php
$result = [
    'email' => 'test@test.com',
    'value' => 758433,
    'key' => 'postalcode',
];
$return = [
    'email' => $result['email'],
    $result['key'] => $result['value'],
];
var_export($return);
```

The above will output the following:

```
array (
  'email' => 'test@test.com',
  'postalcode' => 758433,
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer which made me understand that I had forgotten a detail, so I edited my question. I have more than one result that i would group by email.

Comment: And i think it is possible to get the result i expect from the query directly.